# How can I fix the issue in the TIGER loader that causes it to fetch all files when loading Kansas?

Tags: tiger

I've discovered a bug in the TIGER loading script provided by Postgis 2.1.2.  When loading Kansas (state code 20) I get FTP statements like the following:

```
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010/ZCTA5/2010/*_20* --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=2 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/FACES/*_20* --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=2 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/FEATNAMES/*_20* --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=2 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/EDGES/*_20* --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=2 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
wget ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2013/ADDR/*_20* --no-parent --relative --recursive --level=2 --accept=zip --mirror --reject=html
```

in the loader script.

The problem with these statements is that all of the files in the FTP directories contain a '_2010' or '_2013', which means that these statements attempt to pull all of the files from the FTP source directory, not just the Kansas specific ones.

The problem can be fixed by replacing the '*_20*' with a 'tl_*_20*', but frankly the loader script generation functions are complex, and I'm not sure how to make this change without breaking anything.

The Postgis Github repo doesn't seem to accept issues which aren't pull requests, so I'm posting this question here in the hopes that one of the Postgis maintainers will see it and address the issue.

I can fix this manually for scripts I generate, but I imagine it would be more desirable to fix the root problem.  What's the best way to get this fixed?

Comment: Can you mark the chosen answer as accepted? This is no longer a problem. It's been fixed, and that fix is live.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the best way to get this fixed?

Here's a link to file bugs in PostGIS:
http://postgis.net/support
and here's a link to this particular bug submission so you can track it's progress:
http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/2336

**UPDATE**

> Fixed for postgis 2.1.9 at r13989 and PostGIS 2.2 at r13990